# React component import data from db

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-router, frontend

I'm building a web app with React where I have a component (product.js), with a form connected to a db, and another component where I need to use the data inserted previously in the form. The form is working and is sending the info to the mongodb, but I'm struggling with getting the data to the last component (Output.js) where I need to access that data. The flow is from product.js to another comp, profile.js, and then to output.js. I'm surely missing or doing something wrong but so far haven't been able to make it work. Any help or suggestions on how to do it are greatly appreciated.

Product.js route:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const router = express.Router();

const Product = require('../models/product-model');


// POST route => to create a new product
router.post('/product', (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, price, category } = req.body;
  Product.create({
    name,
    price,
    category
  })
    .then(response => {
      res.json(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.json(err);
    });
});

// GET route => to retrieve a specific product
router.get('/product/:productId', (req, res, next) => {
  Product.findById(req.params.productId)
    .then(product => {
      console.log("this is it>>>>>>>>>>>>>", product)
      res.json(product);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.json(error);
    });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Product.js React component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Products extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { name: "", price: "", category: "" };
  }

  handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.history.push('/profile');
    const name = this.state.name;
    const price = this.state.price;
    const category = this.state.category;
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/product", { name, price, category })
    .then( () => {
        this.props.getData();
        console.log("added to db!");
        this.setState({name: "", price: "", category: ""});
    })
    .catch( error => console.log(error) )
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {  
      const {name, value} = event.target;
      this.setState({[name]: value});
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} onChange={ e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
          <label>Category</label>
          <input type="text" name="category" value={this.state.category} onChange={ e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
          <label>Price</label>
          <input type="number" name="price" value={this.state.price} onChange={ e => this.handleChange(e)} />

          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Products;
```

Output.js component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Output extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProduct();
  }

  getProduct = () => {
    const params  = this.props.match
    console.log(this.props);
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/product/:productId`)
    .then( responseFromApi => {

        console.log("this is it", responseFromApi);
        const theProduct = responseFromApi.data;
        console.log(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>this is the product", theProduct);
        this.setState(theProduct);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.price}</h1>
        <h1>results</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Output;
```

Comment: `axios.get('http://localhost:5000/product/:productId')` are you putting a valid `productId` in here? (in client-side `getProduct`)

Comment: Also possible typo in render, did you mean `{ this.state.theProduct.price }`?